# Porting .Net Framework to .Net Standard/Core Results in Debug Mode Throwing Error "The function evaluation requires all threads to run"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, .net-core, .net-framework-version

I have recently ported/migrated my entire Selenium C# automation solution/framework from .Net Framework to .Net Standard and .Net Core.

After doing so, I realized that while debugging (via Test Explorer) and viewing properties in the popup debug window, I would get "The function evaluation requires all threads to run" errors (See below screenshot).

After seeing this, I checked the Threads window while in debug mode (see screenshot below) and saw that it is multi-threaded (additional threads showing as "not available" and "System.Private.Core ManualResetEventSlim").

The same solution with the same code in .Net Framework is also showing multithread, however, it does not throw any errors while debugging (see screenshot below).

What could have caused this? How do I fix this so that I can debug without getting those errors/having to manually click those little icons to see properties, within the new Net Core

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/eliofek/why-do-we-get-the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to-run

Comment: Have you looked at the thread stacks to try to see what might be creating the threads?

Comment: Could you provide more information about your environment? What tool is running this code? Is it your own executable? A unit test tool like mstest or xunit? A selenium plugin in VS?

Comment: @antiduh My apologies. I did not formulate my question correctly. Both .Net Framework and .Net Core/Standard are showing multiple threads in that Thread window. Please re-read my question, as I have edited it considerably

Comment: @RobertHarvey I read that article. After reading, I am not sure what to think. Is there NOT a setting I can change so that VS ALWAYS executes ALL threads (so then I wouldnt have to manually click the little icon to see properties all the time?). Please reread my question, as I have edited it considerably, showing that .NetFramework did not have this issue.

Comment: Try to apply SingleThreaded to the TestFixture class. To see if it makes any difference

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: It looks like in the second screenshot you are viewing the "HP" properties after having just called another subsequent Navigation.GotoHomepage() and storing those in an "HP2" variable; versus in the first screenshot you are viewing the variables of a single homepage visit. Is it possible that this is playing a factor? Selenium might be loading the second visit which causes a bunch of threads to be in flight at the point where you broke that it depends on to evaluate the properties of "HP".